# Unable to execute a line brake in IDA

Tags: ida

I am new to IDA freeware 7.0 i have tried to insert line brake and i get this message:

> The file can't be loaded by the debugger plugin. Please verify that
>   the parameters are valid.

I could not find which parameter is meant by the error message.

Comment: Please add your code and what you attempted.